# Redirect user to 2FA page Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, redirect

I've got a working login page for my Laravel program. Now, if the user logs in successfully he/she must be redirected to a different page (instead of the "home" page as they normally would have been). This will be the 2FA page.

My question is:

I know how to redirect the user after validating their credentials, but how can I set it so that once the user is redirected to the 2FA page that they cannot instantly access any other part of the website as they would after logging in normally? (Also, they should only be able to access the 2FA page if they've been authenticated successfully) And then only allow them access to the full content of the website only after they've passed the 2FA page?

My login function in my AuthController looks something like this:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password])) {

              return redirect()->route('home');

            } else {
              session()->flash('errormessage','Invalid password.');
              return redirect()->back();
            }
```

As far as I know, "Auth::attempt" immediately logs the user in when True is returned. One way I was thinking of doing it is I instantly log the user out as soon as they're logged in, save their UserID to their session, then redirect them to the 2FA page, the 2FA page checks their UserID in their session and loads, otherwise redirects them back to the login page. And once they've passed the 2FA page just log them in again using their UserID which is saved in their session.

Any better suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to your login controller which overrides the redirectTo property

```
 public function redirectPath()
{

    if(some condition)
    {
         $this->redirectPath=route("some where");
    }else{
         $this->redirectPath=route("some other where");

    }
    return $this->redirectPath;
}
```